# Why does different objects get assigned the same material and how to unlink them?

Tags: materials, linked-data

I have multiple objects that seem to be separate from each other :
[image]

Yet if I change one's material, all of them get changed :
[image]

I tried unlinking them to the material but everything that I do material-wise affects them all.
What's causing this ?

Note: It doesn't happen if I duplicate one of them and change that one's material.

Comment: did you try to go into *Object > Relations > Make Single User > Material*?

Comment: @moonboots Yes, that doesn't seem to fix the problem

Comment: please share your object only: https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: @moonboots The website isn't working for me - https://easyupload.io/a379xo

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These are linked duplications, all the sphere share the same mesh and the same material. You can make all these meshes single users: Go into *Object > Relations > Make Sing User > Object, Data & Materials*:

[image]

If you want your objects to still share the same mesh but different materials, select the object, go into the *Material* panel, click on the *Link* dropdown menu and click on *Object* (or <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd> click on *Object* if you've selected several objects):

[image]